# 2006 Miata Maintenance

Tags: maintenance, mazda, miata

About a year and a half ago, I bought a 2006 Mazda Miata Mx 5 with about 120k miles on it. Now its got about 136k miles. I've kept up with oil changes and filter changes and shes never given me any trouble. But im starting to get worried that she'll crap out on me soon because I hoon her pretty damn hard at times. Is there any advanced preventative maintenance I can do to keep her running longer and better?

Answer (score 2):

The single most important thing you can do is to do regular oil and filter changes. I suggest doing it every 5k miles at most. Other than that, make sure your air intake and fuel injectors are good. If you have traction control, get someone to turn it down a bit to allow more wheelspin. This will ease the strain on your transmission. And if you notice something small, have it fixed before it turns into something big.